# Vue.js: Why is array resetting to its original state?

Tags: vuejs2

I am trying to read data from input and push the data to array: `notes`.
I see it happening, but immediately after that `notes` resets to its original value: `notes: [{title: 'Default Title', detail: 'Default Detail',},],` Why is it happening?
I can stop this by  `v-on:click.prevent="addNotes"`, but why is this happening?

```html
<template>
  <div class="notes">
    <h1>{{ appTitle }}</h1>
    <form>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="noteTitle">Note title</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          class="form-control"
          id="noteTitle"
          placeholder="Enter note title"
          v-model="note.title"
        />
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="noteDetail">Note Detail</label>
          <textarea
            type="text"
            class="form-control"
            id="noteDetail"
            placeholder="Enter Note Detail"
            v-model="note.detail"
          />
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" v-on:click="addNotes">
          Submit
        </button>
        <div class="all-notes">
          <div class="each-note" v-for="(note, index) in notes" v-bind:key="index">
              <h2>{{note.title}}</h2>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      note: {
        title: '',
        detail: '',
      },
      notes: [
        {
          title: 'Default Title',
          detail: 'Default Detail',
        },
      ],
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addNotes() {
      const { title, detail } = this.note;
      debugger;
      this.notes.push({
        title,
        detail,
        date: new Date(Date.now()).toLocaleString(),
      });
    },
  },
  props: {
    appTitle: String,
  },
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because the button is of type submit and it is inside a form. The default behaviour of a submit button is to post the data and then refresh the page. That's why your `.prevent` solution works, it stops the event from propagating and doesn't refresh the page keeping your state as it should be.